# Odoo 10 reading and learning debug terminal file

Tags: ubuntu, logging, odoo, odoo-10

I am new to Linux world.

Is there any sources how to interpret debug log in Ubuntu terminal?

For example I got log here from terminal, logging Odoo 10 process:

```
2018-03-21 05:29:31,817 2296 DEBUG odoo odoo.api: call crm.lead().load_views(options={u'load_fields': False, u'load_filters': True, u'toolbar': True, u'action_id': 141}, views=[[347, u'kanban'], [350, u'list'], [349, u'form'], [None, u'graph'], [None, u'calendar'], [None, u'pivot'], [352, u'search']]) etc...
```

Now, I can understand Odoo objects here, but what is the meaning of 'u' before each options ?

Comment: Step 1: Find out what syntax that uses, I guess it's Python-inspired. Step 2: Read the source code to find out what the messages mean.

Comment: `u'hello world'` is just a unicode string in python.